# Codeigniter - I cannot see database errors

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, autoload

I cannot see the SQL errors in my browser when I navigate to links.

### Details:

CodeIgniter 2.2.0

In my database.php I have

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

And I am trying to connect to an old `MySQL: 5.1.73-cll"

I tested the IP, user and password using MySQL command from linux shell and it works fine, I am able to connect.

But when I add the 'database' to my `$autoload['libraries']` in `autoload.php` my page loads blank completely and there is no error message displayed. If I remove the 'database' from `$autoload['libraries']` then my page loads correctly.

If I could see the error I would at least know what the issue is.

Thanks!
Marius

Comment: Is the `display_errors` setting set in your `php.ini`?

Comment: It is Off. How do I turn it on? I tried nano in php.ini and added 'display_errors = On' but still in phpinfo shows it's off

Comment: You need to restart the web server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I have 'display_errors = On' now but it still shows a blank page. I also changed 'display_startup_errors = On' and still no luck. The 'On' flag is visible in phpinfo() when I check it in browser

Comment: And there is no error in the /var/log/apache2/error.log file

Comment: try this.  remove the @ before the mysql_connect in the system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php

Comment: Hi @Marius. Try answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It looks like the main reason was the fact that php-mysql module was not installed. I had PHP Installed, MySQL installed but not this module. Before that I also updated PHP.ini file, but not sure if that was needed or if the install of php-mysql does it by itself anyways. But here is what I did and hopefully this will help others:

### Steps

**1) Update PHP.INI**

Create a info.php file with the content of

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and launch it to find out the correct location of PHP.INI file. Check the location of PHP.ini file in "Loaded Configuration File" then edit PHP.ini file

```
# sudo nano /etc/php4/apache2/php.ini
```

and scroll down to find the existing setting

```
display_errors = Off
```

and change it to

```
display_errors = On
```

NOTE: There are 2 places where 'display_errors' is mentioned, one close to the top of the file, one a bit below, don't add or uncomment any line in the first section, like I did, as it will be overwritten by the other line below. Just edit the display_errors part by changing 'Off' into 'On', that's what I did

**2) Install php-mysql**

Then install the php-mysql and restart the webserver

```
# sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

**3) Restart web server**

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/apache2.restart
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is adding this at the top of your code -

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Check link:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

**OR**

Also check your **`ENVIRONMENT`**. You can add those settings in your base **`index.php`**

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* ERROR REPORTING
*---------------------------------------------------------------
*
* Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
* By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
*/

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
   switch (ENVIRONMENT)
   {
      case 'development':
        /* Report all errors */
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        /* Display errors in output */
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
      break;

      case 'testing':
      case 'production':
        /* Report all errors except E_NOTICE */
        /* This is the default value set in php.ini */
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

        /* Don't display errors (they can still be logged) */
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
      break;

      default:
          exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see errors in two ways.

Change you php.ini file 
set

```
error_reporting=E_ALL
display_errors="On"
```

After change these you have to restart your apache server.

Another option is
Just add these two following lines in your function:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',"On");
```

No need to restart apache server.